# Editable ComboBox setting caret position using mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, caret, cursor-position

I have a editable wpf combobox. I want to set the caret position to the end of the text whenever it gets focus.

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my answer, the code works for TextBox, not ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this on `GotFocus event`:

```
TextBox textBox = this.combo.ChildrenOfType <TextBox>().
                       FirstOrDefault(element => element.Name == "PART_EditableTextBox");

// if textbox is null then return
if (textBox == null)
{
    return;
} // if textbox == null

// set the caret index of textbox
textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
```

`PART_EditableTextBox` is basically a name of the `TextBox` which provides editing in editable `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks. But I wanted to know if there is any way to do this through mvvm (ie) from the viewmodel.

Comment: This is basically part of the view. It is better to handle view things on View side only